# Wifi not working with lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I just switched to lubuntu 14.04 (was using Ubuntu 11.10 before) and I could not get my wifi to work. I am using BCM4312 LP-PHY. I did the usual steps of removing the blacklist from blacklist.conf, and then installing the b43 firmware packages through synaptics. I also tried command line:

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

After all this, it can detect wireless networks and the wireless light on my laptop comes on. If I do `ifconfig` I see that the wireless seems to be detected.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:6f:1f:41  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

However, when I try to connect to my wireless network, it says that the connection has limited or no connectivity.

Please help. I am a big fan of Ubuntu but I have not spent several hours on this with no luck.

Gaurav

Comment: Same, I am using Asus Vivobook S400CA, Atheros AR498 Wireless Adapter. :(